# Calling R function in Vertica: Failure in UDx RPC call ... Exception in processPartitionForR: [0 (non-NA) cases]

Tags: r, vertica

I have created a transform UDF in R, which runs linear regression over a table partitioned by an Id of some entity. I tested it in console and it worked flawlessly, the results made sense and all was good. However, in the practical setting (code ran by the server, not me manually) with the same data I always see the same error:

ERROR 3399:  Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeProcessPartition(): Error calling processPartition() in User Defined Object [remove_temperature_correlation] at [/scratch_a/release/24506/vbuild/vertica/OSS/UDxFence/RInterface.cpp:1387], error code: 0, message: Exception in processPartitionForR: [0 (non-NA) cases]

Here is the actual function:

```
require('splines')

timefy <- function(time) {
  time = as.POSIXct(time, tz='utc', origin='1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')
  return(time)
}

remove_temperature_correlation <- function(data, params=list()) {
  names(data) = c('Time', 'Value', 'Temperature')

  # Check params
  df = params[['df']]
  if (is.null(df))
    df = 4

  degree = params[['degree']]
  if (is.null(degree))
    degree = 1

  # Convert Vertica timestamps to R's POSIXct format
  data$ct = timefy(data$Time)

  # Fit model
  formula = Value ~ bs(Temperature, df = df, degree = degree)
  fitmodel = lm(formula, data=data)

  data$NormalizedValue = residuals(fitmodel)

  return(data[c('Time', 'Value', 'Temperature', 'NormalizedValue')])
}

remove_temperature_correlation_parameters <- function()
{
  num_params = 2
  param = data.frame(datatype=rep(NA, num_params),
                     length=rep(NA, num_params),
                     scale=rep(NA, num_params),
                     name=rep(NA, num_params))

  param[1,1] = 'int'
  param[1,4] = 'df'

  param[2,1] = 'int'
  param[2,4] = 'degree'

  return(param)
}

remove_temperature_correlation_return_type <- function(x, param)
{
  num_params = 4
  param = data.frame(datatype=rep(NA, num_params),
                     length=rep(NA, num_params),
                     scale=rep(NA, num_params),
                     name=rep(NA, num_params))

  param[1,1] = 'timestamptz'
  param[1,4] = 'Time'

  param[2,1] = 'float'
  param[2,4] = 'Value'

  param[3,1] = 'float'
  param[3,4] = 'Temperature'

  param[4,1] = 'float'
  param[4,4] = 'NormalizedValue'

  return(param)
}

remove_temperature_correlation_factory <- function()
{
  list(name=remove_temperature_correlation,
       udxtype=c('transform'),
       # time, value, temperature
       intype=c('timestamptz', 'float', 'float'),
       outtype=c('any'),
       outtypecallback=remove_temperature_correlation_return_type,
       parametertypecallback=remove_temperature_correlation_parameters,
       volatility=c('stable'),
       strict=c('called_on_null_input'))
}
```

I was trying to simulate a situation that causes similar error in test environment and found that supplying the function with just a single row raises the same error. I'm very new to Vertica and it's UDFs so it would really help if I could get some ideas on how to debug it further and ideas on what could be the cause. Some googling and conversations led me to believe that the cause is in the way the data is partitioned (maybe some empty partitions arriving to the UDF?)

Here is how I call the UDF:

```
create local temporary table TEMP_table
on commit preserve rows
as
SELECT 
    Id,
    remove_temperature_correlation(Time, Value, Temperature USING PARAMETERS df = 4, degree=1)
    OVER(partition by Id order by Time)
FROM temp_input;
```

The temp_input table is simply storing the corresponding data in multiple rows.

What could be the way to solve it, any ideas on how to find out where exactly this error happens and how to handle it?

Comment: Hello Dimitry, how did you deploy your UDX?

Comment: Something along these lines: 
CREATE LIBRARY tempCorr as '/home/dbadmin/RegressTemperature.R' language 'R';
CREATE TRANSFORM FUNCTION remove_temperature_correlation as language 'R' name 'remove_temperature_correlation_factory' library tempCorr;